# AngularJS ([$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at) when value is URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive as below:

```
angular.module('mymodule')
.directive('httpsimg', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment         
             //@ reads the attribute value, = provides two-way binding, & works with functions
       scope: {
            style: '@',
            width: '=',
            height: '=',
            'src': '='
        },
       template: '<img src="{{src}}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" style="{{style}}" />',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

                var srcparts = $scope.src.replace('http','https');
                $scope.src=srcparts;

        } //DOM manipulation
    }
});
```

then I use that in my Html code as below:

```
    <httpsimg src="http://www.mytest.com/imgdir/logo.png" width="50" />
```

if inside my directive change src to one way binding(@) as below:

```
 scope: {
            style: '@',
            width: '=',
            height: '=',
            'src': '@'
        }
```

it works fine, I mean I can get value and there is no error. But if I change @ to = to have two way binding I see the error
Also I found out that the issue is because of Url so if I change the url to a simple world without dot and slash it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

`=` two way binding is to bind *expressions*, e.g. *variables*:

```
<httpsimg src="foo">
```

Where `foo` is a scope variable. `https://…` is most certainly not a scope variable, and is invalid syntax for a variable or expression. If you use `=` binding, you need to supply a literal value as expression literal:

```
<httpsimg src="'http://www.mytest.com/imgdir/logo.png'">
               ^                                     ^
```

Just as you would write a string literal in Javascript. Perhaps to illustrate it even better:

```
<httpsimg src="'http://' + 'www.mytest.com/imgdir/logo.png'">
```

Since you're not binding a variable expression, there's no point in using two way binding. If you just want to pass a literal value, that's exactly what `@` is for.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, Actually, I only want to replace  src in <img /> with this value. I want to replace src here: <img src="{{src}}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" style="{{style}}" /> inside directive template

Comment: Then you need to write `src="src"`, not `{{src}}`. The `src` attribute is already going to be evaluated as expression because of `=`, using `{{}}` double-evaluates it.

Comment: I changed template to '<img src="src" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" style="{{style}}" />' and scope to @, but when I check the result src is not replaced